# stays unknown vs remains unknown

Tags: vocabulary

The original author of the manuscript ___ unknown.

*stays/remains*

Are both of these words ok to use in this sentence? Is there a slight difference in meaning? Which one is more native, better in your opinion?

P.S. It's a question from my exam. And many students argue about the correct answer. We need help of our English friends. Thanks!)

Comment: "remains" is by far the more common choice there. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stays+unknown%2Cremains+unknown&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstays%20unknown%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cremains%20unknown%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Check this too http://www.ozdic.com/collocation-dictionary/unknown

Answer (score 4):

There's a (fairly weak) tendency for ***remain*** to be used of *states, conditions*, whereas ***stay*** is more likely when referring to *locations, attitudes*.

Perhaps linked to that, ***stay*** tends to be used where the subject is *in control* of the attribute/situation continuing without change. Thus,...

> 1: *I remained unmarried until I was 30.*
>    2: *I stayed unmarried until I was 30.*

...where I think #1 is more likely if the speaker would have liked to marry earlier (but circumstances didn't work out as he might have hoped). And #2 is more likely if the speaker *deliberately chose* to enjoy his 20s as a footloose and free bachelor.

For both those reasons, it's better to say *the author **remains** unknown* in OP's context. To me, *the author stays unknown* suggests the author is taking active steps to avoid detection.

---

For what it's worth, here are a few more contexts where the two words aren't likely to be thought of as "interchangeable". But I wouldn't like to say how much they reflect *underlying principles,* as opposed to randomly-established idiomatic preference...

> 3: *Stay back!* (injunction not to come any closer)
>    4: *Don't stay out late!* (injunction to be back reasonably early)
>   5: *I ate everything he gave me, but I remained hungry.*
>   6: *I begged him to reconsider, but he remained implacable.*